# How the understand the idea of spatial dependent Fermi wave vector?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phase-transition, strong-correlated, bosonization

Recently, I have been reading the book by Naoto Nagaosa on [Quantum field theory in Strongly Correlated Electronic Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540659811), but I got a problem in Chapter 3.2. When he discuss the idea of Bosonization in 1-D, he mentioned that

> The idea we started with was the 'Fermi wave number expressed as an operator'. That is, when $k_F+\delta k_{F}^{R}(x,\tau)$ and $-k_F-\delta k_{F}^{L}(x,\tau)$ are Fermi wave numbers of right-moving and left-moving electrons, the electron density is given by $\rho^R(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\delta k_F^R(x,\tau)$ and $\rho^L(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\delta k_F^L(x,\tau)$. That is, the variation of the Fermi wave number is nothing more than the charge fluctuation.

I can understand the point that one can relate the changing of electron density to the variation of Fermi wave vector ( or Fermi energy ), but I am a bit confused about the $\textbf{spatial dependence}$ of the Fermi wave vector, by this I mean, isn't the Fermi wave vector a $\textit{global}$ quantity? like in the free electron case, we have the Brillioun zone of a crystal, and there is the band structure, at zero temperature, we can fill electrons into the band up to the Fermi energy/wave vector.

So how should we understand this $\textbf{x}$-dependence in the Fermi wave vector? And what would be the $\textbf{state}$ with this kind of spatial-dependent wave vector?

By the way, Mr. Nagaosa already referred to this point at Chapter 2 of the book, where he first discussed the idea of Bosonization.